# Inline dialog opened when page loaded

Tags: oracle-apex

In one of my application pages I created an inline dialog region. that region should be opened and closed using dynamic actions only.
I don't know why it's opened when the page loaded without any action, how to prevent it from opened in that case? any suggestions?

Comment: My first guess would be that the dynamic action > action that opens this dialog has the attribute "Fire on initialization" set to yes.

Comment: No, it isn't. Anyway I resolve it, the dynamic action is IG selection changed. and In IG, the _Select First Row_ attribute was enabled, so I just disabled it. Thanks @KoenLostrie, your gues help me to move one step forward.